# "DLL reference error" in windows 8 system in vs 2010

Tags: vb.net

when i ported windows application VS2002 to VS2010 and use ported project in Windows 8 system with VS 2010. some AxInterop dll giving reference error in project(all AxInterop dll showing yellow triangle). 
(Note: i didn't create that dll.)

Comment: Is this third party DLL or your own DLL? Are you on the same platform 32bit to 32bit/ 64bit to 64bit?

Comment: Can you add more details about what you are trying to run?

Comment: These might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287839/what-is-the-difference-between-axinterop-and-interop and: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122250/how-to-generate-axinterop-files